# Pentaho User Console Dashboard Preview Showing Empty Data - Need Help Troubleshooting

Tags: visualization, datasource, pentaho, dashboard, pgadmin-4

I encountered an issue while working with Pentaho User Console. Here are the details of the problem:

1 Data Source Upload: I initially uploaded my data source from pgAdmin 4 into Pentaho User Console.

2 Dashboard Creation: Subsequently, I created a dashboard using this data source.

3 Empty Preview: However, when I attempt to preview the dashboard, it displays no data, appearing completely empty.

4 Data Exists: I can confirm that there is indeed data present in the data source. Therefore, there should be information to display on the dashboard.

I expected the dashboard to display the data from my data source, as it should, based on the data I uploaded. However, it is currently showing an empty preview.
I am seeking assistance from the Stack Overflow community to help me identify and resolve this issue so that I can successfully visualize the data on my Pentaho dashboard. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.